# How big is the core of a supergiant star before it collapses into a neutron star?

Tags: astrophysics, neutron-stars

What is the typical mass and density of the core of a supergiant star before it collapses into a neutron star?

Comment: [Stellar core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_core)

Comment: 30 Doradus? Sanduleak?

Comment: good explanation of this at wikipedia.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing it there. The Stellar Core article doesn't mention the mass of the core, and the only densities listed are for stars that aren't massive enough to collapse to a neutron star. Where specifically do you see the mass and density of the core of a star that will collapse to a neutron star?

Comment: Sure, let's do Sanduleak. I'm trying to understand the density of the neutron star compared to the density of the same material before the collapse.